# Is there something like &nbsp for '?

Tags: php, html

The system I'm using has a bug dealing with `'`,is there a html format for `'`?

Is there a PHP function to look up this ?

Comment: You are suppose to accept the answers .. If they are satisfying ..

Comment: Are you sure that your system has a bug with quotes and that it's not just a programming error? Is it the bug on your server or on your client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
htmlentities ($string, ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 9):

There is `&#39;`.

Take a look at the [HTML page on these codes.](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)

Comment: Is there a PHP function for this?

Comment: I don't think so, google found this: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/convert-special-characters-to-html-entities-between-code-tags

Answer (score 3):

`&rsquo;` for ’ and `&lsquo;` for ‘

[Found from here](http://www.webmonkey.com/reference/Special_Characters)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
&#39;
```

See it in action (not much to look at): '

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference: http://www.asciitable.com/ is always a good help :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference chart for html special characters:

http://www.mindflip.com/inet/web/htmlchars.html

You can try `&#39;` or `&#145;` for a quote.

Answer (score 1):

You can also to use `&apos;`

Answer (score 1):

```
Character   Entity Number     Entity Name         Description

   "         &#34;                &quot;          quotation mark

   '         &#39;                &apos;          apostrophe(does not work in IE)  

   &         &#38;                &amp;           ampersand

   <         &#60;                &lt;            less-than

   >         &#62;                &gt;            greater-than
```

Comment: Note that it's only &apos; that isn't supported as widely.

Answer (score 0):

What about [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)()?